# Giving array of float to libmfcc library

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters, mfcc

I want to use `libmfcc` library for computing these coefficients. But I have an array of floats. And function `getCoefficinet` wants an array of doubles. I tried to overwrite parameters of this function, but it still doesn't work. The best solution would be if I got floats from this function. And what is parameter size, is it a size of input array or something different?

```
    int freq = 44100, filter = 48, size = 1024, mfccCount = 26; //const
    float realPartArray = new float[size]; //input spectral array
    double mfccArray = new double[mfccCount]; //output array
    for (int i = 0; i < mfccCount; i++)
        mfccArray[i] = getCoefficient(realPartArray, freq, filter, size, i);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass an array of one type to a function that expects an array of another type. That may be possible in other languages, but it's impossible in C/C++. And please don't try to cast them, you will get ugly results in the best case and a segmentation fault in the worst case.

You need to copy all values of one array to the other. The compiler will take care of casting the floats to doubles, but the loop needs to be written by you :) It's a easy task, two lines of code plus some braces.

Your variable `size` is obviously the number of samples. You need that for your loop.

One small advice: Even if this is valid code

```
for (int i = 0; i < mfccCount; i++)
    mfccArray[i] = getCoefficient(realPartArray, freq, filter, size, i);
```

Please consider using braces every time you have a `if`, `for`, `while` statement. Next time you want to extend that statement, you will know why

```
for (int i = 0; i < mfccCount; i++)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    mfccArray[i] = getCoefficient(realPartArray, freq, filter, size, i);
```

Ouch!

Comment: Do you want to share some details? What have you done exactly? Do you get any compiler error? Linker error? Do you get a result that doesn't match your expectations? I'm sorry, I can't read your mind.

Comment: Btw: You can update your question above with these details, you don't have to provide them here (comments are very limited for that).

Comment: I tried your solution, but function GetCoefficient still doesn't work.
Error: undefined reference to GetCoefficient(double*, uint, uint, uint,uint);
I delete file from my project and then add it, but it doesn't help. Rebuild, clear too. Do you have any idea, why it does this?
https://paste2.org/CDY2JJXO

Comment: "undefined reference to..." is a linker error. Are you compiling the file `libmfcc.c` as well? It's not enough to include the header file, you need to compile that code as well! Or link it as a library. There a plenty of examples out there, the comment section is too limited to allow me to explain that here.

Comment: Btw, thanks for posting your code! But please be careful with your array sizes. What size does `preMfccArray` have? 1024 or 513? Please recheck that, or you will get unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is that libmfcc waiting for the FFT array on input, as far as the sequence is next:

```
1: wave signal ---> get window 1 ---> do FFT on window 1 ---> getCoefs
2: wave signal ---> get window 1 ---> do FFT on window 2 ---> getCoefs
...
N: wave signal ---> get window N ---> do FFT on window N ---> getCoefs
```

That first, second:

in documentation they noted that array they're waiting to get may be prepared using [fftw3](http://www.fftw.org/) library. So the pseudocode would be like:

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <libmfcc.h>

...

double **func(double *in) {
  double *out = NULL;
  double **mfccArray = NULL;
  // allocate memory, set variables...

  // Do fft on "in", in real life you'll be using Windows like (Hann, etc.) and
  //    you will split input into parts with overlapping like this:
  // in:[1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,7,4,2,3,4]
  // window_size = 4; window_step = 2;
  // wnd[1]:[1,2,3,2]
  // wnd[2]:[3,2,1,2]
  // ...

  plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

  // Do MFCC loops here:

  mfccArray[i] = getCoefficient(out, freq, filter, size, i);


  return mfccArray;
}
```

I hope this we'll help a bit. Sorry for the late answer.